# Unresolved import in documentation example

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I'm having difficulty fixing an error inside my documentation example for my library. I have the file structure like for my crate `bignum`

```
.
|-- Cargo.lock
|-- Cargo.toml
|-- examples
|   |-- dat
|   |   `-- euler_13.dat
|   |-- debug.rs
|   `-- euler_13.rs
|-- README.md
|-- src
|   |-- error.rs
|   |-- inits.rs
|   `-- lib.rs
```

In my examples, my headers will look something like

```
// euler_13.rs 
extern crate bignum;
use bignum::inits::Zero;

// ...
```

This compiles and works great, but now when I'm writing an example inside my documentation at `lib.rs`, I can't seem to import `bignum::inits::Zero`

````
//lib.rs
//...

impl BigNum {

    //...


    /// Constructs a ...
    ///
    /// # Examples
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate bignum;
    /// use bignum::inits::Zero;
    ///
    /// let a = bignum::BigNum::new(Zero::zero());
    /// ```
    ///
    pub fn new(base: BigNum) -> BigNum {
        // ...
    }
````

When I run `cargo test`, I receive this error

```
     Running target/debug/lib-fe3dd7a75a504b04

running 3 tests
test crate_from_u32 ... ok
test create_from_string ... ok
test adding_no_carry ... ok

test result: ok. 3 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

   Doc-tests bignum

running 1 test
test new_0 ... FAILED

failures:

---- new_0 stdout ----
    <anon>:3:9: 3:15 error: unresolved import `self::bignum::inits::Zero`. Did you mean `self::self::bignum::inits`?
<anon>:3     use self::bignum::inits::Zero;
                 ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
thread 'new_0' panicked at 'Box<Any>', /home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libsyntax/diagnostic.rs:192



failures:
    new_0
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035491/error-using-local-modules-in-documentation-tests) question, but this deals with importing modules from the same file which still require toplevel scope. However here i'm still specifying top level scope with `bignum::`.

So while importing `bignum::inits::Zero` works for all of my tests and examples, it doesn't work for my docs. Why is that? I've tried appending `self::` in front and receive the same error. If i change the doc examples to

```
extern crate bignum;

let a = bignum::BigNum::new(bignum::inits::Zero::zero());
```

it compiles fine however. How can I correctly import my modules?

Comment: @Shepmaster so while I think these are different questions, the other answer actually did solve my issue. I think it's because my problem is that in the `# Examples`, `extern create bignum` is implicit, so doing so again will create errors. I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27301) with a recommendation on changing the error output for this type of error

Comment: Sure, I'll go ahead and do that

Comment: Off-topic: is it possible not to remove my comments when I suggest a duplicate? It's very frustrating to author a message only to see it disappeared after a while. This is the [second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609137/why-are-explicit-lifetimes-needed-in-rust) it happens.

Comment: @mdup AFAIK, if the duplicate suggestion is accepted, that comment that came from the suggestion is auto removed. My only suggestion is to split it into two comments or not use the close link if you are just suggesting.

Comment: @Shepmaster ok, will do that next time. By the way I never used a close vote (not enough rep yet). It would be nice if the comment was restored after the question is unduplicated.

Comment: @mdup if you didn't use the close link to suggest the duplicate, I'm surprised about the behavior. It may be worth asking a question on [meta].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem stems from this [useful feature of the doc tests](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/documentation.html#documentation-as-tests):

> rustdoc will automatically add a `main()` wrapper around your code, and in the right place.

If you apply the rules in the link, you end up compiling code like this:

```
fn main() {
   extern crate bignum;
   use bignum::inits::Zero;

   let a = bignum::BigNum::new(Zero::zero());
}
```

You would then indeed need to refer to it as `self::bignum`, as the first error message suggests. Unfortunately, that won't currently work because of [Rust issue 23314](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23314).

Comment: ah, so that's the explanation behind **why** it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

So the reason this error is generated boils down to `extern crate bignum` implicitly being used by the documentation examples, meaning I shouldn't need to explicitly tell the example I'll be using `bignum`.

This makes sense because at the documentation level, examples show how the functionality of a specific part of your crate should work, so you'll be using `bignum` regardless. cargo recognizes this and imports `bignum` for you. What the example **should** look like is:

````
//lib.rs
//...

impl BigNum {

    //...


    /// Constructs a ...
    ///
    /// # Examples
    ///
    /// ```
    /// use bignum::inits::Zero;
    ///
    /// let a = bignum::BigNum::new(Zero::zero());
    /// ```
    ///
    pub fn new(base: BigNum) -> BigNum {
        // ...
    }
}
````